# HTML CSS Table Cell Width

Tags: html, css, html-table

I'm trying to understand if it is possible to set the width of a table cell or column to either:

1. a fixed `%` width
2. a fixed `px` width

And, regardless of its content - it stay that width.

However, the scenario is that the first column needs to be longer than the rest.  So if I have 10 columns, the first is larger and the other 9 are equally spaced.

I have tried the following but it does not work:

```
table{display:block;overflow:hidden;}
th td {max-width:2%;overflow:hidden;white-space:nowrap;}
th.question {width:60%;overflow:hidden;white-space:nowrap;}
td.question {width:60%;overflow:hidden;white-space:nowrap;}
```

Is it possible to achieve a `fixed width`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to achieve a fixed width

Yes , if you set the propertie to `fixed` for the `table-layout` rule on `<table>` or on any `display`ed as `table` element.

See W3C : http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/table-layout

Comment: Thanks for the reply - however, this creates all columns to be equally spaced - which is not the solution I am looking for, as described above.

Comment: give a try and understand how this works, else why should i answer :)

Comment: I've added `table-layout: fixed;` to the code above and no joy.

Comment: Can you give a link to a fiddle or codepen so, we see how you applied width and table-layout :)

Comment: I've been playing and you can set the width of columns in a 'fixed' width scenario and all working as it should!